# How do I programmatically disable/enable the physical keyboard in Android?

Tags: android, api, keyboard, usb

I have an application that I'm developing that uses a USB HID device connected to a Motorola Xoom for some input. However, the majority of the time I still want to use the on-screen keyboard.

Is there a way to disable/enable the use of hardware keyboard in Android 3.0+? I'd like the application to behave like it would, had there not been a keyboard connected.

Comment: IMHO this is definitely bad for your application usability. The user will be frustrated because he/she can't use his/her keyboard. Try to make a more flexible application.

Comment: Besides I don't think there's a way: Why do you want to do that? If you app is receiving input from the user, why would you care where it comes from and not leave the choice to the user?

Answer (score 0):

well one solution you can think of is ..

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onKeyLongPress(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    return true;
}
```

this will avoid any actions during keyboard key press. but there is no way you can disable android keyboard since it will use some native methods.