# How to disable Android HARDKEYBOARD keyboard?

Tags: android, android-keypad

I am trying to disable\freeze android hard keyboard from an Android Activity using the following pieces of code.But none is working.

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden"
```

in manifest file.

Also inside Activity

```
Configuration config = getResources().getConfiguration();
        config.hardKeyboardHidden=1;
```

Please let me know how to disable the hardkeyboard from an Activity in android?

Comment: There are already such questions on Stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7118810/how-do-i-programmatically-disable-enable-the-physical-keyboard-in-android

Comment: Check this as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12511140/disable-hard-keyboard-input-for-edittext-in-android

Comment: I am trying to freeze the keyboard for 3 secs.During which i will show a advertisement.But i am unable to do that.I am searching...i think that's not possible.

Comment: I'd rather suggest to load the advertisement in an AsyncTask: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: show progress bar in `onPreExecute()` and hide the progress bar in `onPostExecute(Result)`. While the progress bar is visible, the activity cannot take any input from the user, that means you'll not have to disable the keyboard anymore. Disabling the keyboard is not a good way.